# find character at last of line in python file move it to start of line

Tags: python, file

I have to read one python file and whenever i get } closing curly braces at the end of line move it to start of line
for eg.
input.py

```
print("hello") 
print("shankar")}
```

required output

```
print("hello") 
}
print("shankar")
```

current output getting now

```
print("hello") 
}print("shankar")}
```

code

```
pattern='}'
f = open('input.py', 'r')
g = open('tempo.py', 'w')
l=f.readlines()
f.close()
for ind in range(len(l)):
    if pattern in l[ind]:
        l[ind]= "}" + l[ind]
        l[ind] = l[ind].rstrip("}")
for field in l:
    g.write(field)
g.close()
print('Done')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to consider the newline character:

```
    pattern='}'
    f = open('input.py', 'r')
    g = open('tempo.py', 'w')
    l=f.readlines()
    f.close()
    for ind in range(len(l)):
        if pattern in l[ind]:
            l[ind]= "}" + l[ind]
            l[ind] = l[ind].replace("}\n","\n")
    for field in l:
        g.write(field)
    g.close()

print('Done')
```

note: if your line break is windows-like then you may need to do `replace ("}\r\n","\r\n")`